# Measuring meta-intelligence

Tags: measurement, metacognition

Does anyone know of any research in measuring [metacognitive abilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacognition) (i.e. metacomprehension, metamemory, meta-emotions(?), etc) in people? In other words, I'm wondering if the same way we have IQ tests (which I know is a whole other topic of debate), if there would be a way to measure "meta-IQ"?

Comment: What [initial research](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/66/29) have you done on this? What would be "high metacognition" what would be low? Usually if you can't come up with tags for your questions then it is a sign that you haven't framed it well enough by existing knowledge to have a well answerable question.

Comment: I think that the definitions of high metacognition vs low metacognition are pretty intuitive. I have done little initial research. (I'm not a cog sci researcher, just a curious individual). And the tags are there: "metacognition" and "measurement"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good overview on the topic is [Metacognition: A Literature Review](http://www.pearsonassessments.com/hai/images/tmrs/Metacognition_Literature_Review_Final.pdf) (E. R. Lai), page 27 has a section assessing the measures of Metacognition.

> Flavell (1979) describes 
>   assessment tasks that asked children to study a set of items until they were sure they could 
>   remember them completely. Children were then tested on their ability to recall all the items.
>
> Another common task was to read a set of written instructions and indicate any omissions, 
>   mistakes, or areas of ambiguity. Schneider (2008) observes that the most studied type of 
>   procedural metamemory is self-monitoring. Assessments designed to capture this ability include 
>   ease of learning judgments, judgments of learning, and feelings of knowing. For example, ease 
>   of learning judgments typically ask students to study a set of test materials for a short amount of 
>   time and then assess their abilities to remember the material. After the students are tested on the 
>   material, their performances are compared to their initial predictions.

Generally assessments focus on one specific area of Metacognition like Metamemory.

See also [Development and Validation of an Objective Measure of Metacognition](http://www.eric.ed.gov/ERICWebPortal/search/detailmini.jsp?_nfpb=true&_&ERICExtSearch_SearchValue_0=ED383725&ERICExtSearch_SearchType_0=no&accno=ED383725) that assess four studies evaluating metacognitive abilities.

Searching around on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) finds a great deal of studies using and proposing various measures for Metacognition. There's certainly no "standard" like an IQ test, as Metacoginiton: A Literature Review notes, part of the challenge in studying and teaching Metacognitive abilities is due to the lack of focus on them in traditional school curriculum.